# App keeps crashing with malloc issue objective c and c

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

Question- I want to be able to run my c code over and over again however after the first execution of it in my objective c it crashes and I receive an error in xcode "Thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACESSS (code=1, address=0x0)". It's really strange because the first time I run it works then any time after that it dies on me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Here is my c code

funcc.c

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFLEN 1024
#define MYFREE(x) free(x); x = NULL;

char const *ipcc;
char *statuss;
char *both_words;
char *s1;
char *s2;
char *results;

void concat()
{
    **// THIS IS THE LINE I RECIEVE THE EXC_BAD_ACCESS ERROR/////************** results

    results = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    strcpy(results, s1);
    strcat(results, s2);
    both_words = results;

    return;
}

char* P(const char *ipAddr)
{
    int pipe_arr[2];
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    pipe(pipe_arr);

    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipe_arr[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        execl("/sbin/ping", "ping", "-c 1", ipAddr, (char*)NULL);
    }
    else //parent
    {
        wait(NULL);
        read(pipe_arr[0], buf, BUFLEN);

        char *xxx = deblank(buf);
        char *input = xxx;
        char delimiter[] = " ";
        char *i, *j, *remainder, *context;

        int inputLength = strlen(input);

        char *inputCopy = (char*) calloc(inputLength + 1, sizeof(char));
        strncpy(inputCopy, input, inputLength);

        i = strtok_r (NULL, delimiter, &context);
        j = strtok_r (NULL, delimiter, &context);
        remainder = context;

        s1 = i;
        s2 = j;
        concat();

        char *sx = search(both_words);

        //getchar();
    }

    close(pipe_arr[0]);
    close(pipe_arr[1]);

    return both_words;
}


void ConnectionMain(){
    char *val = P(ipcc);
    printf("%s\n", val);
    char *valb = "0packets";
    if(strcmp(val, valb) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "noconnection");
        statuss = "noconnection";
        //free(concat);
        //return "noconneciton";
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", "connected");
        statuss = "connected";
        //free(concat);
        //return "connected";
    }
    s1 = NULL;
    s2 = NULL;
    results = NULL;
    both_words = NULL;
    ipcc = NULL;

}
```

funcc.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

extern const char *ipcc;

extern char *statuss;

//const char *TestConnection(const char *ip);

void ConnectionMain();
```

## Here is my objective c code

ViewCtrl.m

```
- (void)checkconnection
{
    ConnectionMain();
    //const char *ipc = [ip UTF8String];
    //TestConnection(ipc);
    char *statuss1 = "noconnection";
    NSString* xx = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:statuss];
    //printf("%s\n", statuss);
    if(strcmp(statuss, statuss1) == 0)
    {
      _ip_label.stringValue = @"No Connection";

      //I TRIED SETTING THESE BACK TO NULL BUT STILL NO LUCK 
      // I ALSO TRIED FREE(CONCAT) STILL NO LUCK 

      ipcc = NULL;
      statuss = NULL;
      statuss1 = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      //I TRIED SETTING THESE BACK TO NULL BUT STILL NO LUCK 
      // I ALSO TRIED FREE(CONCAT) STILL NO LUCK 

      _ip_label.stringValue = @"Connection Success";
      ipcc = NULL;
      statuss = NULL;
      statuss1 = NULL;

    }


}

- (IBAction)ipButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    //THIS IS WHERE I EXECUTE MY C CODE///////*********

    NSString *ip_text = _ip_text_box.stringValue;
    const char *ipxx = [ip_text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    ipcc = ipxx;

   [self checkconnection];

}
```

Comment: `strncpy(inputCopy, input, inputLength);` won't NULL terminate. Why don't you use `strdup` ?

Comment: How would I use strdup in this situation? @Jean-FrançoisFabre